# How to set a non standard language in DHTML

Tags: php, html, css, dhtml

Hi I want to set hindi language as default in my web page. how can I do that. How to set languages in dhtml? any body knows the solution please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HTML `lang` attribute to specify this:

```
<html lang="hi">
```

Comment: Further reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide [hindi font unicodes](http://unicode.org/standard/translations/hindi.html) support:

- [What is Unicode? (Hindi)](http://unicode.org/standard/translations/hindi.html)
- [Display Problems?](http://www.unicode.org/help/display_problems.html)

Otherwise you can create bitmaps of your hindi text in any bitmap editor and place these bitmaps to your website.